# What are the risks of prolonged nicotine gum use?

Tags: mental-health, physical-health, recreational-drugs, tobacco

Looking to get an idea of the physical risks/effects, though mental effects would be good to know as well.

Main purpose in asking is to persuade someone with *some* medical knowledge to quite nicotine entirely, but I'm coming up short on concrete health risks.

So far, the best source I've found is this one, but it is not specifically about nicotine gum, doesn't go into detail on the degree of risk and seems to include some studies of tobacco products effects on the organs rather than just nicotine.
https://www.thieme-connect.de/products/ejournals/pdf/10.4103/0971-5851.151771.pdf

Comment: Welcome to Medical Sciences! Questions here are required to show results of prior research. As described in the [help] and the[reasons mentioned in [this meta post](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/q/411), this demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and helps you get more specific and relevant answers. Please [edit] your question with links to or references to what you've found in your search. Otherwise your question may be closed.

Comment: Specifically, are you sure there are health risks associated with nicotine if it's not being delivered by smoking or vaping? Have you tried googling that? After all, nicotine gum and patches got FDA approval and the FDA generally won't approve things unless the benefits outweigh the risks.

Comment: Roger that, Carey! Will add what I've found so far shortly. One issue is that many sources are vague or simply refer to short term effects of nicotine use, with no mention of greater or compounding risks for years of use.

I'm also specifically looking for information about the gum, as I imagine that the effect of adsorbing the membrane of the gums has its own particular issues separate from what a patch or spray might have.